# my friend loves a boy and they said qabol hai intext mesgs to each other?

Tags: nikah

My friend is 22 yrs old and she loves a guy, one day they accept each other in text message in the presence of their male friend in the goupe mesg,

they said like qabol hai ori accept Ahmad son of mahmod az my husbandetout any mehr so is the nikkah is vslid?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. For further information about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please note we are not a fatwa site.

Comment: On what basis would this nikah be valid. Where are the witnesses who saw/heard this where is the guardian of the girl who gave his agreement in first place? Mahr is something ordered by Allah in the qur'an it is a right of the bride. Please note that nikah and Talaq are serious matters which shouldn't be taken in such a lite way. There are enough posts on the site that should answer this question. Further use meaningful and relevant tags.